# Undefined columns

Tags: r, seqhmm

I am trying to implement HMM in R. Right now I have 18 columns in my dataset. When I am making an emission matrix, it gives an error of undefined columns, I don't know where I am doing it wrong.

```
library(seqHMM)

emix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 4)
emix[1,] <- seqstatf(exam_seq[, 1:5])[, 3] + 1
emix[2,] <- seqstatf(exam_seq[, 6:12])
emix[3,] <- seqstatf(exam_seq[, 13:18])

Error in \`[.data.frame`(seqstatf(exam_seq[, 1:5]), , 3) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

**Data** posted by the OP in a comment.

```
structure(list(Freq = c(260, 262, 74, 1, 485, 106, 6, 
219, 215, 1282, 80), Percent = c(8.69565217391304, 
8.76254180602007, 2.47491638795987, 0.0334448160535117, 
16.2207357859532, 3.54515050167224, 0.20066889632107, 
7.32441471571906, 7.19063545150502, 42.876254180602, 
2.67558528428094 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c("So", "Da", "UK", "Tw", "Al", "Ab", "D", "NA", "0", "1", 
"2"))
```

Comment: Can you post output of `dput(seqstatf(exam_seq[, 1:5]))`?

Comment: @markus**structure(list(Freq = c(260, 262, 74, 1, 485, 106, 6, 219, 215, 
1282, 80), Percent = c(8.69565217391304, 8.76254180602007, 2.47491638795987, 
0.0334448160535117, 16.2207357859532, 3.54515050167224, 0.20066889632107, 
7.32441471571906, 7.19063545150502, 42.876254180602, 2.67558528428094
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("So", "Da", "UK", "Tw", 
"Al", "Ab", "D", "NA", "0", "1", "2"))**

Comment: Thats the output @markus ^

Comment: You create `emix` with 3 rows and 4 columns, the dataset you have posted has 11 rows and 2 columns. Also, where does function `seqstatf` come from?

Comment: @AymenTasneem The output you posted has two columns and you want to select the third one. That's why the error.

Comment: @RuiBarradas How did u know that dataset has 2 columns? I am following an example of HMM that I found on a website, they used this function **seqstatf** for emission matrices.

Comment: @markus These are the first 3 rows of my dataset and it has 18 columns, `    Sequence                                             
1   So-Al-1-1-1-2-1-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0                
2   Da-Al-1-1-1-2-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-1                
3   Da-Al-1-1-1-2-0-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0    ` @RuiBarradas ,

Comment: Your dataset has two columns, `Freq` and `Percent` and 11 rows, as can be seen by counting argument `row.names` or with base function `dim`. As for the second issue, function `seqstatf`, the question still holds, can you provide us with a link to it?

Comment: [link] (https://rdrr.io/cran/seqHMM/src/R/build_hmm.R)
Here is the example that I am following, I ran this example and it gave no error, but when I try to run it on my dataset, the emission matrix is giving an error. @RuiBarradas

Comment: The link should be to CRAN package [seqHMM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqHMM/index.html).

Comment: @RuiBarradas did you check the link?

Comment: Yes, I have. I believe that what you are doing wrong is to run the same code on your dataset, you should try to understand how the example is applied to *that* data and then adapt to your problem.

Comment: I molded my data according to this example. I have 18 columns with 0 and 1 values. the code I mentioned only works for the first row of emix matrix and not reading the rest of the columns of my dataset. The error is  _"incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"_ or _"undefined columns selected"_  As I am new to R so its difficult for me to interpret the error and correct my code accordingly. @RuiBarradas

Comment: @RuiBarradas Is there any other way to find emission probabilities for a given dataset?